# Is it possible to name Android's views by JAVA?

Tags: java, android

If I have made a button:

```
Button btn = new Button(this);
```

Now I want to name this button in order to identify this view.

Is it possible to name the Android's views like giving ID and class to an element in HTML?

(I know Android view has a `id` attribute, but the id can't be named by program.

For example:

If there is a function like this:

```
Random random = new Random();
setViewName("btn"+random.nextInt(100));
```

So is there any way to name the view by program?)

Comment: You already named it. You named it `btn`.

Comment: No, but after `btn`, I want to put some random number. THis should be named by JAVA program.

Comment: Is it possible to name the views dynamically by JAVA? I have searched Google, but have no ideas.

Comment: @Audit Lock then put the button in a data structure where you can look it up, such as a map.

Comment: If you want to do this, you're probably doing something wrong.  Attempting to treat Android like a html dom will lead to inefficient and buggy code.  There's almost certainly a better way of doing things.  Like keeping the button around in a variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set a Tag to the button.

```
Button btn = new Button(this);
btn.setTag("Some Button!");
```

Then you can identify the button by calling:

```
btn.getTag();
```

Comment: Thanks. By the way, can two different views name a same tag?

Comment: Yes that is possible, hence a tag is no unique identifier.